# What exactly does -x option mean in Perl if

Tags: perl, if-statement

I know no Perl, so please be patient!
This is a bit from the script, that generates the error:

```
    if (-x '/usr/bin/gcc') {
        $gcc = Fink::Services::enforce_gcc(<<GCC_MSG);
Under CURRENT_SYSTEM, Fink must be bootstrapped or updated with gcc
EXPECTED_GCC, however, you currently have gcc INSTALLED_GCC selected.
This typically is due to alteration of symlinks which were
installed by Xcode. To correct this problem, you will need
to restore the compiler symlinks to the configuration that
Apple provides.
GCC_MSG
        $gcc = "-gcc" . $gcc;
    }
```

This script installs fink package manager on Macs. (I'm not a Mac user, trying to help out my friend to install a program that is originally a GNU program and needs to be compiled from sources).

The install script complains about the version of GCC being not what it expects. I suspect that this is the place that fails, but don't quite understand what is it doing.

I've tried creating a symlink to the installed GCC, which is version 4.2.1, while fink wants version 4.2.

This message is displayed if I put a symlink to GCC into /usr/bin. Otherwise it identifies the version of GCC properly and refuses to install.

I thought that `-x` switch is similar to Bash and means that it is checking that the file is an executable, but I'm not sure what exactly does it do in Perl and would it treat a link to an executable as executable?

Thanks!

Comment: `-x` and friends are just standard functions, and so can be found in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Alphabetical-Listing-of-Perl-Functions): "-x  File is executable by effective uid/gid."

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Alphabetical-Listing-of-Perl-Functions

Comment: @wvxvw It is a somewhat odd construct to find for the first time :) The other alternative would have been `perlop` (also part of the standard perl documentation).

Comment: @wvxvw Then ask a new question or reword the existing question. Also with a minimal test-case of `-x` (in bash) vs. `-x` (in Perl) if they should differ from expectations.

Comment: @wvxvw So then fix the title. It is amazing how a good (or not good) title (or other opening) can make or break content ..

Comment: I would start a new question. Symlinks aren't really specific to Perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it test is the file has the executable bit set.
in your case: `chmod -x /usr/bin/gcc` will cause your `if` block to no execute.
`chmod +x /usr/bin/gcc` will casue your `if` block to get execute.

Comment: @wvxw All stat operations follow symlinks by default — that is, you're testing the properties of the thing the link points to, not the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perl's file test operators (you can see the documentation using the command: perldoc -f -x) usually do follow symlinks, with the exceptions of `-l` and `lstat()`.  If you specifically want to test the link rather than the target, you can first do one of those, and then test `-x _`; `_` as an argument makes it reuse the last stat results.

Answer (score 0):

```
-X  File is executable by real uid/gid
```

Comment: the accepted answer says `it test is the file has the executable bit set.`. so its the same what I said (as per Perldoc)